# How do I evaluate this integral involving monomial and trig?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos nx dx$$

This is the integral I have to evaluate. I have a table of standard integrals from [Integral Table](http://integral-table.com/integral-table.html#SECTION00008000000000000000) which says that integrals of such forms evaluate to:
$$
\frac{\cos x}{n} + \frac{n\sin x}{n}
$$
However, the textbook provided in college says the numerator of $nSinx$ should be $n^2$ and hence I end up with the wrong answer.

Can someone please explain to me how I can go about evaluating this ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Integration by parts with $u=x$.

You can use the identity

> $$ \cos(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx} }{2}. $$

But, still you have to use integration by parts.

Comment: Ok check the answer I posted to `Ayush Khaitan` and please, tell me if the identity is right / wrong (link in question) cause integrating by  parts is not an option in the exam. Not enough time.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\cdot\cos {nx}\,dx}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{x}{n}\sin {nx}\bigg|_{0}^{\pi}-\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin {nx}}{n}\,dx}\right]$$

Should be straightforward from here.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\pi n^2}[-1^n -1]$